# Webpack There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have something like this:

```
WARNING in C:/Data/.../letsTest.jsx
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Data\...\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=stage-2!C:\Data\...\letsTest.jsx
    Used by 4 module(s), i. e.
    multi C:/Data/Doc/13/13080801/LetsTest/letsTest.jsx
* C:\Data\...\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=stage-2!c:\Data\...\letsTest.jsx
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Data\...\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=stage-2!C:\Data\...\r1HeadLearning.js
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, I found the answer.
It was a Windows issue. It was necessary to change the absolute path in C:\Data...\r1HeadLearning.js  from

```
c:\Data\...\letsTest.jsx
```

to

```
C:\Data\...\letsTest.jsx
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, small case "c" and capital "C" produces different results.

Comment: damn my mind filtered completely the drive letter... sorry

Comment: In your case, what was producing those paths? I don't know what to edit :/

Answer (score 1):

Delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` 
That fixed my problem

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue if you are module dependencies that have the same filename like isarray and buffer

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same warnings on my system, where I'm coding a Create-React-App on Windows 10. Since the Windows file system is not case sensitive, this did not prevent me from continuing to work, but it was ugly to look at on my terminal output. In investigating, none of the available answers helped me. But in a few days of ruminating on the problem I thought of a possible cause. In the recent past I had used npm a couple of times to install modules instead of my usual yarn. Since the warnings were all pointing to node-modules, I decided that could have been a mistake. So here is what I did:

1. First I merged my develop branch into my master branch, getting everything into one branch.
2. Next I deleted the entire node_modules folder.
3. Then I ran yarn install to load all the package.json modules.
4. Finally I did a yarn start, and the warnings were gone.

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

From Contributing.md in create-react-app:

> The scripts in tasks folder and other scripts in package.json will not work in Windows out of the box. However, using Bash on windows makes it easier to use those scripts without any workarounds.

so, the easier way is to just install Bash and `npm install` there. the steps are:

> #### Install Bash on Ubuntu on Windows
>
> A good step by step guide can be found
>   [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)
>
> #### Install Node.js and yarn
>
> Even if you have node and yarn installed on your windows, it would not
>   be accessible from the bash shell. You would have to install it again.
>   Installing via
>   [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) is
>   recommended.
>
> #### Line endings
>
> By default git would use `CRLF` line endings which would cause the
>   scripts to fail. You can change it for this repo only by setting
>   `autocrlf` to false by running `git config core.autocrlf false`. You
>   can also enable it for all your repos by using the `--global` flag if
>   you wish to do so.